# mod rewrite - multiple variables

Tags: mod-rewrite

Apologies if this is a basic solution but mod rewrite still give me gip.

I have a current mod rewrite rule to convert a slug into a usable variable like so:

```
RewriteRule ^/c/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?.*$ /content.asp?slug=$1 [L]
```

I need to add a second, optional variable. Only the slug matters, the second variable may or may not be there.

> www.domain.com/this-is-the-slug/

and

> www.domain.com/this-is-the-slug/optional-variable/

should both work. I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/c/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?.*$ /content.asp?slug=$1&scotland=$2 [L]
```

But now every page (without the optional variable) just redirects to the root.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out.

I need both rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/c/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?.*$ /content.asp?slug=$1&scotland=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/c/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?.*$ /content.asp?slug=$1 [L]
```